# Prove that death is an invariant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

An outlaw is escaping in a car traveling with a speed of $v_o$ in the positive $x$ direction (as measured form a stationary observer on the side of the road). A police officer, chasing in a vehicle traveling at a speed of $v_p$ also in the positive $x$ direction (as seen by the same observer), fires a bullet with a muzzle speed (speed relative to the gun) of $v_m$.

Show that, depending on the values of the various velocities, the bullet either hits the outlaw in all Lorentz frames or misses the outlaw in all Lorentz frames (i.e. there are no velocities for which the bullet hits the outlaw in some Lorentz frames but does not reach the outlaw in another Lorentz frame).

How will I know that bullet misses the outlaw?

Answer (score 2):

If I draw two curves they either intersect or they do not intersect. They cannot intersect if I describe them in, say , Cartesian co-ordinates but not intersect if I describe them in, say, polar co-ordinates. The property of intersection is an intrinsic property of the curves themselves, and does not depend on how I describe them.

Similarly, the world lines (trajectories in spacetime) of the bullet and the outlaw will either intersect or not intersect. They cannot intersect in some reference frames but not in others.

Answer (score 0):

The bullet misses if its world line never intersects the outlaw’s.